# Изменить расширениекартинок при загрузке страницы. ASP.NET Core

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net, core

Задача такая. При загрузке страниц на старых устройствах, которые не поддерживают расширение картинок .webp, нужно поменять его на .png. Как распознать учтройство, теоретически понятно. А как поменять расширение картинок? Часть кода Html, в котором есть ссылка на картинки, поднружается с помощью @Html.Raw(Model.Text). Смотрел в сторону JQuery, но не пойсу, как реализовать логику. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
<div>
    <!--...some Html...-->
    <div class="col-lg-4 d-none d-lg-block about-img-block">
        <img src="/Images/Design/design1.webp" />
        <img src="/Images/Design/design2.webp" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: пример содержимого Model.Text приложите в вопрос

Comment: Приложил пример в вопрос.

Comment: можете просто replace сделать .webp на .png

Comment: А как именно его сделать? Я приложил скрипт, который пытаюсь применить, но он не работает. Что-то упускаю.

Comment: менять надо тут @Html.Raw(Model.Text) кодом на c#: в начале странички: @{string sText = Model.Text; sText = sText.Replace(".webp", ".png")} , а подставлять уже так: @Html.Raw(sText)

Answer (score 0):

Получилось, так работает:

```
<script>
    $('img').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('src').includes(".webp")) {
            let src = $(this).attr('src');
            src = src.replace(".webp", ".png");
            $(this).attr('src', src);
        }
    }); 
</script>
```